# Function score for validity period documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that stores promo information. There are `valid_start_dt` and `valid_end_dt` fields in each document. What is the optimal decay scoring relative to current time, so that:

- Promo that still valid get higher score than expired promo and upcoming promo
- Valid promo with shorter validity period get higher score than valid promo with longer validity period
- Recent Expired promo still get non zero scoring, higher than older expired promo
- Upcoming promo has higher score than expired promo

Note that the function score will be used in this query template:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [{ "terms": { ... } }],
          "must" : [
            { "terms": { ... } }
          ],
          "should": [
            { "terms": { ... } },
            { "terms": { ... } }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
           // ??? ///
      ]
    }
  }
}
```